# Extract data from mongoDB with rmongodb

Tags: r, mongodb, database, nosql

I have the following code in R:

```
library("rmongodb")

mongo <- mongo.create(<host>)
mongo.is.connected(mongo)
collection<-mongo.get.database.collections(mongo, 'words')
store <-mongo.find.all(mongo,collection)
```

When I print the store I get:

```
[[1]] [[1]]$`_id` [1] "56c462be97819a3e6320e595"

[[1]]$word [1] "short"


[[2]] [[2]]$`_id` [1] "56c462c597819a3e6320e596"

[[2]]$word [1] "long"
```

The problem here is that I don't how to get the the whole word field and how to get a single entry, like 'short' and 'long'.

I've searched for some time and still don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

```
mongo.get.values(mongo, "words", "word")
```

## Another example:

```
cursor <- mongo.find(mongo, "words", query='{"word":"short"}')

list <- mongo.cursor.to.list(cursor)
```

helpful cheatsheet:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmongodb/vignettes/rmongodb_cheat_sheet.pdf

hope that helps!